# Silence or condense IPython parallel exceptions

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to silence the details of a composite exception containing the errors IPython parallel workers? I have a large cluster (500+ workers) and if my (bad) code throws an exception on all workers, it takes forever for the exception to parse and render in the IPython Notebook. I'd like to just silence the details of the worker errors and get one, simple tiny exception back with the details from a single worker since the rest tend to be the same in my usage.

I know I can switch my DirectView to point to one worker to test my code, but I'd be handy not to manipulate the dview and instead just set a global flag to avoid giant stack traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: ask this question
Step 2: checkout [this Pull Request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2871)

If you just want to see the first exception, you can register a custom exception handler that does exactly that:

```
from IPython.parallel import error
def only_the_first(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset=None):
    value.print_traceback(0)

ip = get_ipython()
ip.set_custom_exc((error.CompositeError, ), only_the_first)
```